# How to generate jar file from package?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following project, I am trying to generate jar file from it.

[image: Folder's structure]

I tried a ton of methods and I cannot properly generate the jar file, I think the problem is the folders structure, I also have to include the .xlsx as it it part of my program.
When I try to clean and build it generates the .jar file but when i try to run it I get an error
I also tried to manually specify the main class in the Manifest.txt and compile it.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class NewJFrame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewJFrame
```

What are the correct steps I should follow?
I mention that the "NewJFrame" is the class that has the main inside

The pom structure is :

[Pom Structure](https://pastebin.com/vaAghZGN)

Comment: it would be useful if you can share your pom file and also how you are trying to run your jar. You may need to create a far jar.

Comment: And you may still have some issue even after you create your fat jar depending on how you load the files.

Comment: @cool I added the pom structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into your pom file. And you will have a single far jar which contains all the dependencies you need and everything.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                     <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: When I try to run it with java -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar i get the following error : no main manifest attribute, in mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the archive part. Please change the pom to introduce acrhive part with the proper main class. I update the config above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not as easy as it sounds... To run a Jar, you need to have:

- The jar you want to run. In your case, this is the Jar generated from your IDE command
- A classpath, with all the dependencies. Usually, those dependencies are managed by your IDE, which is the reason why you can run your app with the IDE. But when you generate a JAR, with Maven for instance, then you no longer have your IDE managing the dependencies for you.

So let's say you have a basic application with Maven, with NO dependencies, you could do the following:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

Then, to generate the JAR, you run `man package`. To run it, do the following (no need for manifest file):

```
java -cp target/myApp.jar com.stackoverflow.test.Main
```

Here, you can see the "-cp" option, which instructs the JVM to load a JAR, in our case, located in target and named myApp.jar, and execute the main method inside the class `com.stackoverflow.test.Main`.

Easy right ?

But then, things get more complicated when you start having dependencies. In my following example, I'll assume I have a dependency with a famous library. I'll update my POM accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>launchJar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

And then, I'll use this API in my code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringUtils.upperCase("Hello World !"));
    }
}
```

Once I generated the Jar (`mvn package`) and execute the same command as before, I have your error:

```
java -cp target/myApp.jar com.stackoverflow.test.Main
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils at com.stackoverflow.test.Main.main(Main.java:8)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> ... 1 more

The only way to get it to work is by adding my new dependencies to the classpath, in order to run the application. With maven, in my example, the `commons-lang3` dependencies is located in: `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar`.

In order for my application to run, I execute:

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.9/commons-lang3-3.9.jar:target/myApp.jar com.stackoverflow.test.Main
```

Note:

- To run the application, the classpath order is important (commons-lang before my Jar)
- On Unix/Linux, to separate different JARs, the character is `:` . On windows, use `;`

But then, what happens if I have lots of dependencies, will I need to provide them manually ? Fortunately, no :D

With Maven, you can use a new plugin, which creates a so-called "fat jar", or "jar with dependencies". To do so, just update your POM to add a new plugin:

```
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

Then, with `man package` you have a new JAR created, called: myApp-with-dependencies.jar.
To run it, execute:

```
java -cp target/myApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.stackoverflow.test.Main
```

You could also customize this plugin to automatically add a MainClass and have a "runnable Jar".

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.test.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

And then, just run:

```
java -jar target/myApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```